# proving existence of a crossing point

Tags: real-analysis

Given are two cars, that travel the distance from city A to city B in the same time.

We have to show that there is (at least one) point in time $t_0$, when the two cars have exactly the same speed.

I approached this as follows:

- let $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t) : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ describe the speed with respect to time of both cars, respectively.
- we know that $f_1(0) = f_2(0) = f_1(1) = f_2(1) = 0$ and $f_{1,2} \geq 0$
- we have to show $\exists t_0 \in [0,1]: f_1(t_0) = f_2(t_0)$

Which basically means that I have to show that the there's at least one cross point in the plot of the two graphs. How to show this? I was thinking about constructing another pair of helper functions, so that I get this point $t_0$ to the x-axis, which would enable me to apply the zero value theorem, but I'm a bit cluseles when it comes to finding such a pair of functions.

Comment: You have to make use of the hypothesis that the cars go the same distance.

Comment: So that means that the definite integral of the both functions is the same, but how does this help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f_1(t),f_2(t)$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f_1(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f_2(t)dt$. So that $\int_{0}^{1}(f_1-f_2)(t)dt=0$. Use mean value theorem for integrals for the function $f_1-f_2$ and observe that $\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that $(f_1-f_2)(c)=\frac{1}{1-0}\int_{0}^{1}(f_1-f_2)(t)dt=0$ and hence $f_1(c)=f_2(c)$.